# Java RegExp: Replacing quotes "" for english ones “” (mind context)

Tags: java, regex, typography

Is there any simple way to transform quotes on keyboard to english ones by regular expression, but make sure, that HTML entities are preserved? For instance, we want to translate `some "text"`, but we don't want `<span id="blah">`.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Some of you suggested, that I had not tried myself. I had tried - I did not want to show not to influence you. But with no success:

```
string.replace(
     "(?<!\"|\\w|=)\"(?!\\ |\")((?:[^\"]++|\")+?)(?<!\\ |\")\"(?![\"A-Za-z\u00C0-\u02FF\u0370-\u1EFF])()", 
     "“$1”");
```

But I can't manage not to translate those quotes in HTML Tags.

Comment: And what we want is [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).?

Comment: Re your edit: It's *always* better to show code than not.

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expressions for this will be troublesome, because HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Your use-case is so limited (basically, just skipping the quotes around attribute values) that with sufficient effort (on your part) you might be able to come up with a regular expression for it, but I'd be doubtful (not least because there can be any amount of any kind of whitespace between the `=` and the `"` in attributes, which could make them look a lot like text).

To do this reliably, you'll have to genuinely *parse* the HTML, and only process the non-markup text. You don't have to write the parser, though, you can use any of the several that have already been written. [JSoup](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CHIQFjAC&url=http://jsoup.org/&ei=h9a4T_TTPM358QOR0r3MCg&usg=AFQjCNGlZWM77KWn7rklyQkcisWaUuAq0w) is a particularly well-known one.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if you were only accessing text nodes in a DOM and not operating on a string. But if you insist:

Avoiding quotes in html tags can be achieved with a negative lookahead, something like:

```
(?![^<>]*>)
```

Which says to **not** match if there is a series of characters (following the preceding part of the expression) which does not contain a `<` or a `>` but which is then followed by a `>` (i.e. you are processing part of an html tag)

If you need simple replacement of `"` by another character, let's say a `”`, in the style of swedish quotes, this is easy:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\"](?![^<>]*>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<a href=\"foo bar\">\"test\"</a>");
String str = m.replaceAll("”");
```

If you, however, need to replace the first quote with one thing and the second quote with another, it's more of a pain, and I therefore leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: This does, of course, fail if you have a `>` anywhere in your actual text (which is perfectly valid to do in HTML, even if it's poor practice). E.g., change your string to `"<a href=\"foo bar\">\"a > b\"</a>"` and the `"` prior to `a` is unchanged. That and the fact it doesn't handle both kinds of quotes (which surely is not optional) makes this not very useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed in HTML5, but your example string is invalid. The spare `>` should be `&gt;`. OPs main problem was not matching inside HTML tags. OPs secondary problem is deciding which character to replace the matched quote with. I also recommend that OP use a HTML parser rather than this method.

Comment: @ beerbajay: No, this isn't a change, and no, my example string is not invalid HTML. `>` is perfectly valid in text, and not particularly uncommon (I would always use `&gt;`, but a lot of people don't, and I'm not sure I can really justify why I do). `>` only has special meaning (closing the tag) when you're within a tag. Try using [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/) on it, even in HTML4 strict. Note that `>` is also perfectly valid within the text of an attribute (but I don't think your regex has a problem with that).

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day. Thanks. It even works in xhtml 1.1! I guess my answer, like most situations involving regex, depends on being able to make strong assumptions about your data.

Comment: @ beerbajay: :-) Yeah. (I'm a bit surprised to hear `>` in text is valid XML -- like you said, learn something new every day, thanks!)